# Alter database from Read-Only to Regular mode? A warm-standby database is read-only (Error 5063)

Tags: sql-server, read-only-database, alter-database

I am trying to change the mode of database from "Standby / Read-Only" to "Normal" mode so that I could use mdf file to attach to other SQL Server.

One instruction that I got was go to Properties --> Options --> State --> change the Database Read-Only from True to False.

[image]

Then I got this error message:
**A warm-standby database is read-only.**

[image]

Why do I get this error message and what should I do to change the mode?

Comment: Are you trying to change the state of a replicated database?

Comment: @Ronaldo Yes. I am trying to attach database to other SQL Server, and it appears that I need to make it a "regular" mode. So, I am trying to change from "Read-Only" to "regular". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Standby / Read-Only` database a log shipping secondary.  To bring it online run recovery.  EG

`RESTORE DATABASE FOO WITH RECOVERY`

See generally [Fail Over to a Log Shipping Secondary (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/fail-over-to-a-log-shipping-secondary-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: How do I change from "Read-Only" mode to "normal" mode?